# ActivityTestRule - how to call code before Application's onCreate

Tags: android, unit-testing, integration-testing, android-espresso

I am using Espresso 2.1 with ActivityTestRule, and I am looking for a way to set some static flags before `onCreate()` in my application will be called.

I have some init code that I don't want called during instrumentation tests.

Comment: How about a `static { ... }` block?

Comment: I have tried that. Unfortunately any code in instrumentation test will be called after Application instance has been created. Maybe there is a way to test if app is running in instrumentation?

Comment: I'm kind of unclear on what you're saying, can you post your code?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Application** `onCreate()` is called after Instrumentation `onCreate()`. For this case you need to implement a custom test runner which will subclass AndroidJUnitRunner and will override the callApplicationOnCreate() with your custom setup.

```
public class MyCustomTestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {
@Override
public void callApplicationOnCreate(Application app) {
    InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getSharedPreferences().doMyStuff();
    super.callApplicationOnCreate(app);
}
}
```

Make sure to update your defaultConfig in the build.gradle to use new testInstrumentationRunner like this:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "com.myapp.MyCustomTestRunner"
```

If you are looking to run some code before **Activity** `onCreate()`, subclass ActivityTestRule with your own implementation of `beforeActivityLaunched()`

Comment: This doesn't work for Junit 4 tests. Have you had any luck using AndroidJUnit4 ?

Comment: This is for junit4 tests. I think you are mixing two things -  a class runner and [instrumentation runner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html). Class runner remains the same (AndroidJUnit4), while your instrumentation runner is a custom one. It's actually quite interesting - I completely forgot to annotate some of the classes with @runwith and it didn't seem to impact anything. I am not sure if you even need it anymore, unless you have some customization going on.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful. I'm now however experiencing an error where I get the error "Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.mypackage.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}" . How do I properly set testInstrumentationRunner in build.gradle? Thanks again.

Comment: Oh,this one is in the ```android { defaultConfig { testInstrumentationRunner "com.myapp.MyCustomTestRunner" }}```  of your app gradle file. Make sure to update the run configuration in your IDE as well. If you are using android studio it's in the "Specific Instrumentation Runner" .

Comment: Is it possible to use this runner for only some tests?